# Trying to Reclaim an Old Username on Instagram for a Second Account

Tags: instagram

I'm facing a puzzling situation and I hope you can help me out. About three months ago, I changed the username on my first Instagram account (let's call it "username1" to "username2"). Now, I want to use "username1" for my second account, but Instagram seems to be blocking my efforts.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or knows why Instagram might be preventing me from using my old username? I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions or insights on how to resolve this dilemma.